# What is a good way to traverse through a big file in c++

Tags: c++, file, parsing, hashmap, iostream

I have really big files, which contain data packages. The file itself is simply a really big string, and the packages are seperated with a string "PACK1.0".

Assuming "XXX" is data, a package looks like this :

```
PACK1.0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXPACK1.0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXPACK1.0XXXXXXXXXX
```

I am creating a hash map which contains the number of packages, and the bytes where it begins.

Example:

```
PACKAGE NR | BYTE WHERE IT BEGINS IN THE STREAM
0 | 0
1 | 128
2 | 256
. | .
. | .
```

If I want package number 5340, I look in the hashmap at which byte the package begins, go to the byte with stream.seekg(POSITION) and parse the package, in theory.

My final problem is: I want to travel trough the file with a slider, with play&pause options. My thought was that the slider has a min=0 and max=packagecount range.

Is this a good way to traverse through a file?

What problems can this cause? What is a better way to do this?

This is my Code for storing the hashmap (this code assumes a package is 128byte long) :

```
 std::map<int, int> THEMAP;

    thefile.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
    dataLength=thefile.tellg();
    thefile.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

    while(position<dataLength)
    {
    thefile.seekg(0,position);
    position=position+128;
    packagecount++;
    THEMAP.insert(std::make_pair(packagecount,position));
    }
```

Comment: Considering that package numbers are sequential integers starting at zero, an array or vector sounds more appropriate than a hashmap.

Comment: Not to mention that if your packages are all the same size and that size is known ahead of time, you don't need to keep a map. You can just multiply the package size with the package number.

Comment: actually, the size could change..i work with local files, but it could also be possible to retrieve data over network with TCP.

Comment: What do you mean by "really big"? Can it get that big that it doesn't possibly fit in memory?

Comment: it could have at least 1 GB i think, this would fit in nearly every memory, but i dont want my program to consume so much when i can do it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

This is usuually a case for memory-mapped-io (MMIO). If you are Windows only then use the [MapViewOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the other functions in that family. For cross-platform usage I recommend glib's [file map functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-mapped-file-new). What MMIO does is to map a part of a file (or an entire file) into the process' memory space, so you can access it via a simple pointer. You can determine which part of the file and which size of it is mapped, arbitrarily.

A possible strategy for you could be that you, on startup, map a fixed block of the file into memory in a loop, block by block) and search for the first package identifer in each block. This is relatively quick and gives you a first set of markers. On next access you can use this initial set to find the proper part of the file, map this and scan only this part. Of course, you'd store any marker that comes along.

Later, when you scroll through your file you just map the page (can be smaller this time, depending on how much data you need at a certain point in time) and display the needed data. Obviously, the address of the package markers can at the same time be used as start address for the memory mapping.

Nice side effects are that it is completely irrelevant what size the packages are and you can map files of any size, even gigabyte sized files. By using small views on the file the memory requirement of your application can be very small.